# min() and max() give error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

```
markList=[]
Lmark=0
Hmark=0
while True:
    mark=float(input("Enter your marks here(Click -1 to exit)"))
    if mark == -1:  break
    markList.append(mark)

    markList.sort()
    mid = len(markList)//2
    if len(markList)%2==0:
        median=(markList[mid]+ markList[mid-1])/2
        print("Median:", median)

    else:
        print("Median:" , markList[mid])

    Lmark==(min(mark))
    print("The lowest mark is", Lmark)

    Hmark==(max(mark))
    print("The highest mark is", Hmark)
```

My program is a basic grade calculator using lists. My program asks the user to input their grades into a list in which it then calculates your average and finds your lowest and highest mark. I have found the average but I can't seem to figure out how to find the lowest and highest grade. Can you please show me pr tell me what to do?

Comment: That's a very badly chosen question title. Also it seems like you're *nearly* there. `lowest_mark = min(markList)` would work, you're calling `min()` on the last added value.

Comment: In `Lmark==(min(mark))` and `Hmark==(max(mark))`, `==` is not an assignment but a comparision. Try to use `=` instead.

Comment: It said, 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: I think executing `min` and `max` on the list each time to get the corresponding values as @millimoose suggested is not necessary. In your algorithm you've already sorted the list before you assign min and max, so you just can take the first and last element of your sorted list.

Comment: To take the first and last number in my list would i just do this. marklist[0] and marklist[-1]

Comment: The reason it said 'float' object is not iterable is that you are calling `min(mark)` rather than `min(markList)` as @millimoose suggested.  Change it to find min of the whole list, and likewise change the `max()` statement to find max of the whole list.  `mark` is a single mark, and `min()` doesn't know what to do with a single `float` value so you get the exception.

Comment: Yes, once you have sorted the list, `markList[0] == min(markList)` will be true, and `markList[-1] == max(markList)` will be true.  BTW the way you wrote this, it will recompute everything for each mark entered.  That's fine for debugging, but once you have it working I guess you will want to unindent the code below the input loop.

Comment: probably tou want `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`

Comment: @FKaria This isn't C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with your code:

- `==` is a comparison operator, not an assignment
- mark is your last grade, not the list of grades

Those min/max lines should read:

```
Lmark = min(markList)
Hmark = max(markList)
```

or, since your list has already been sorted:

```
Lmark = markList[0]
Hmark = markList[-1]
```